# Hive not creating separate directories for skewed table

Tags: hadoop, hive

My hive version is 1.2.1. I am trying to create a skewed table but it clearly doesn't seem to be working. Here is my table creation script:-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.mytable
(
country string,
payload string
)
PARTITIONED BY (year int,month int,day int,hour int)
SKEWED BY (country) on ('USA','Brazil') STORED AS DIRECTORIES
STORED AS TEXTFILE;


INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mydb.mytable PARTITION(year = 2019, month = 10, day=05, hour=18)
SELECT country,payload FROM mydb.mysource;
```

The select query returns names of countries and some associated string data (payload). So, based on the way I have specified skewing on the column 'country' I was expecting the insert statement to cause creation of separate directories for USA & Brazil (the select query returns enough rows with country as USA & Brazil), but this clearly didn't happen. I see that hive created directory called '**HIVE_DEFAULT_LIST_BUCKETING_DIR_NAME**' and all the values went into a single file in that directory. Skewed table is only supposed to send rows with default values (those not specified in table creation statement) to common directory (which is what HIVE_DEFAULT_LIST_BUCKETING_DIR_NAME seems to be) and should create dedicated directories for the rows with skew values. But instead all is going to the default directory and the other directory isn't even created. Do I have to toggle any hive options to make this thing work?

Comment: it looks like old bug, doesn't look like it's fixed yet.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13697

Answer (score 0):

It looks like old bug, doesn't look like it's fixed yet.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13697. Basically internally when Hive stores these skew values specified during the table creation, they are converted to lower case before storing in the metastore. That's why the workaround for now is to convert case in the select statement so it goes to the right bucket. I tested this and this way it works.